# Why was the Captain America exhibit in the Air and Space Museum?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, captain-america, captain-america-the-winter-soldier

In *Captain America: The Winter Soldier,* Steve visits an [exhibit](http://marvel-movies.wikia.com/wiki/Captain_America_Exhibit) about Captain America and the his Howling Commandos. This exhibit is in the Smithsonian Air and Space museum.

However, Captain America and the Howling Commandos seem to have had almost nothing to do with Air or Space. They sometimes used planes to get places, but the exhibit doesn't place any emphases on that.

Wouldn't the Smithsonian Museum of American History be a better choice?

I'm fine with in- or out-of-universe answers for why the exhibit was in the Air and Space Museum.

Comment: There is or was an Enola Gay exhibit in the real Air & Space with further displays about its crew; it is possible that the Cap exhibit was an adjunct to some aircraft which he and/or the Howlers were closely associated with.

Comment: Of all the Smithsonian museums, I definitely most quickly associate Air & Space with, well, child-attention-grabbing gimmicky exhibits. Certainly not all of them (and hey, I still like the gimmicky exhibits as an adult!), but it doesn't surprise me all that much.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

### In-universe

Although Captain America had a sizeable comicbook following *prior* to his real adventures, his two major (real world) escapades were both **airborne**; The infiltration of the [Hydra Weapons Facility](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Austrian_HYDRA_Weapons_Facility) and his heroic suicide in the Hydra bomber, [Valkyrie](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Valkyrie)

Bearing in mind his close association with air power, it makes good sense for Steve (and the Howling Commandos, who evidently were also no strangers to air-drops) to be found in a museum devoted to...

> ...maintain[ing] the world's largest and most significant collection of
>   aviation and space artifacts, encompassing all aspects of human flight

---

### Out of universe

Alas, the reasons for choosing the museum as a filming location are pretty mundane:

- The Museum has a [substantial tradition](http://siarchives.si.edu/history/smithsonian-movies) of working with the [Hollywood studios](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1055369/)
- The Air and Space Museum was conveniently located to where the bulk of the film was being made.
- Over [100 of the film's crew](http://www.imdb.com/search/name?roles=tt1055369,tt1843866) had already filmed extensively in the Smithsonian's Air and Space Museum in Virginia when making Transformers 3, meaning that they were knowledgeable about the museum's pre-conditions, safety regulations, contractual obligations, etc

---

For the record, it's worth noting that the  museum's (real world) curator, Margaret Weitekamp has openly [acknowledged the incongruity](http://www.washingtonian.com/blogs/afterhours/movies/heres-what-it-takes-to-film-a-hollywood-blockbuster-in-the-smithsonian.php) between their normal exhibits and the film's depiction of her museum:

> *Though the museum has curated pop-culture exhibits in the past,
>   Weitekamp says it has no plans to produce any tie-in programs with the
>   Avengers series. **“Our focus is on spaceflight, and this is a very
>   earthbound film,”** she says.*

Comment: The American History Museum is only about five minutes away from the Air and Space Museum, so point number two doesn't make sense.

Comment: @RogueJedi - Location might not be the *deciding* factor, but it explains why they ruled out the Texas Museum of Science and the New Orleans WWII Museum, for instance

Comment: of note, TF3 was in the *other* Air & Space Museum. TF3 takes place in virginia, out by Dulles airport. TWS takes place in the Mall in DC. many logistics may not be quite the same between the two locations.

Comment: @phantom42 - I've made that a little clearer. I've not mentioned things like parking, logistics, faciities, etc because obviously those would be different.

Comment: Wait, his "heroic suicide"? Umm, no. https://youtu.be/ruMO9SXto0Q?t=23s

Comment: Was there an Air Force in WWII? I thought it was still part of the Army at that point.

Comment: @Broklynite - The USAF was commissioned in 1947.

Comment: Right, thought as much. Maybe in MCU Cap was in the Army Air Command or whatever it was called.

Answer (score 11):

Possibly because the Museum of American History just recently finished [renovations](http://americanhistory.si.edu/museum/renovation), which, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Museum_of_American_History), began in 2012.  Since much of the museum has been inaccessible for a few years, including during the time that *Winter Solder* is set, it makes sense that the exhibit would be placed in a different museum.

Also, not every exhibit there is explicitly "Air and Space," as evidenced by the [Transformers Exhibit](http://airandspace.si.edu/exhibitions/transformers/).

Comment: The transformers come from space.

Comment: the transformers exhibit was right next to the sr-71 - the same model that jetfire was in *revenge of the fallen*

Comment: The Transformers exhibit is there because they filmed a scene there, so it isn't a normal example.

Comment: "Transformers, robots in the *sky*"

Comment: @MikeHarris Don't you mean, "robots in *disguise*"?

Comment: @DaveJohnson That was from "'Scuse Me While I Kiss This Guy," a collection of mis-heard song lyrics.

Comment: @MikeHarris Ha.  Did you know I actually googled "robots in the sky" first to make sure *I* hadn't misheard it all my life? lol